# Exibir Ocutar Senha usando EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, senhas

Estou usando LabelFor, queria que ao clicar em cima para digitar a senha, fosse exibido os caracteres, e quando clicar fora fosse ocultado, como poderia fazer?

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Senha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Altere o tipo do input para "text" quando estiver em foco (onfocus), quando não estiver, altere para password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lógica seria o seguinte: quando o elemento [`<input />`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) receber o foco, precisa ser alterado o atributo [`type`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) para `text` e quando perder o foco deve ser alterado o [`type`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) para `password`

**Segue** ***exemplos***:

---

[***jQuery***](http://jquery.com/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#Senha').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).attr('type', 'text');
  }).on('blur', function() {
    $(this).attr('type', 'password');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="password" id="Senha" name="Senha" value="123" />
```

[***Javascript***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript):

```js
(function() {
   var senha = document.getElementById('Senha');
   senha.addEventListener('blur', function()
   {
     senha.setAttribute("type", "password");
   });
   senha.addEventListener('focus', function()
   {
     senha.setAttribute("type", "text");
   });
})();
```

```html
<input type="password" id="Senha" name="Senha" value="123" />
```

---

```js
window.onload = function()
{
   var senha = document.getElementById('Senha');        
   senha.addEventListener('blur', function()
   {
     senha.setAttribute("type", "password");
   });
   senha.addEventListener('focus', function()
   {
     senha.setAttribute("type", "text");
   });
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="Senha" name="Senha" value="123" />
```

**Referencias:**

- [*HTML DOM setAttribute() Method*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)
- [*onload Event*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)
- [HTML  Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)
- [HTML Input Types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

Comment: Valeu, era isso que eu procurava

Comment: Fiz também uma edição colocando com `javascript`.

Comment: eu vi, mas com Jquery já resolveu me problema. Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução mais simples. Basta colocar o atributo HTML type, conforme abaixo:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password"}})
```